# Installing VS2010 and WM7 SDK side by side?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am not able to install VS2010 and WM7's SDK side by side. Has anyone been successful with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Beta 1 / 2 and the WM7 SDK are not compatible, but the RC is.

Answer (score 2):

It is supported([msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428633(VS.92).aspx)). Are you using [VS 2010 RC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx) along with Windows Phone Developer Express?